# Ui-router not routing by url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

router change view by uri

my current router is

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "header": { templateUrl: "partials/header.html"},
                "mainContent": { templateUrl: "partials/mainContent.html"},
                "footer": { templateUrl: "partials/footer.html"}
            }
        })
        .state('lesson', {
            url: "/1",
            views: {
                "header": { templateUrl: "partials/header.html"},
                "mainContent": { templateUrl: "partials/lesson.html"},
                "footer": { templateUrl: "partials/footer.html"}
            }
        })
```

when i go into localhost/

i see the main state

but when i go to localhost/1
i still get the main state.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Try changing the url for the main state to `"/"` instead of blank... I'm guessing since it's currently blank, it's defaulting to that state no matter what.

Comment: If i do that i get a blank page, no state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, applying html5 mode fixes this.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```